# Array values changed automatically to 0

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Today I had a strange encounter with gcc. consider the following code:

```
float len[ELEM+1];
len[1]=1.0; len[2]=2.0; len[3]=3.0;                                 //length

nod[1][1] = 1;
nod[1][2] = 2;
nod[2][1] = 2;
nod[2][2] = 3;
nod[3][1] = 3;
nod[3][2] = 4;                //CONNECTIVITY


for(i=1;i<nnod;i++)
  for(j=1;j<nfree;j++)
/* blah blah.........*/
```

**And a variation:**

```
float len[ELEM+1];
len[1]=1.0; len[2]=2.0; len[3]=3.0;                                 //length

nod[1][1] = 1;
nod[1][2] = 2;
nod[2][1] = 2;
nod[2][2] = 3;
nod[3][1] = 3;
nod[3][2] = 4;                //CONNECTIVITY
```

**len[1]=1.0; len[2]=2.0;**

```
for(i=1;i<=nnod;i++)
  for(j=1;j<=nfree;j++)
/* blah blah.........*/
```

The only difference is highlighted in bold.The problem is this:
When length is later printed, the first code prints len[1] and len[2] (and uses them in expressions) as 0.0000 while the second code is printing and using the correct values of those variables.

**What's wrong? I'm utterly confused.:-o**

*Note: len is not modified anywhere else.*

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear due to the amount of relevant information that you have removed. Can you post a minimal, but compile-able, code sample that demonstrates this problem so that we can see it for ourselves? Also, you are aware that in C and C++ array indexes start at zero, not one, right?

Comment: Post some real, compilable code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: and don't make assumptions. If len ends up with a different value than you thought, then most likeiy it *is* modified somewhere else. One of the most fundamental facts of debugging is that the bug exists because your assumptions about the code are *wrong*. And so you obviously can't trust these assumptions to tell you where the bug is, or isn't.

Comment: @jaif: I wrote the code. So I *know* it is not modified. At least manually i mean.
Others have suggested buffer overrun. I'll see to it.
I know array starts with zero. I didn't like it too, but my boss wants it that way. :(

Comment: @Akilan: You know that you didn't *intend* to modify the value. But somewhere it is modified, and it wasn't supposed to be modified. So we can logically conclude that it gets modified somewhere where it wasn't supposed to happen. ;)

Comment: @akilan: That was exactly jalf's point. You think you "know" len isn't being modified, but it *is*. Otherwise, you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @jalf: yes, it did. Buffer overwrite. my mistake. Thanks to all for your comments. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to show us the definitions for `nod`. There's a good chance (based on the fact you're starting arrays at 1, not 0) that you're overwriting memory.

For example, if nod is defined as:

```
int nod[3][2];
```

the possible array subscripts are `0-2` and `0-1`, *not* `1-3` and `1-2`:

```
nod[0][0]   nod[1][0]   nod[2][0]
nod[0][1]   nod[1][1]   nod[2][1]
```

If that *is* the case, you're memory is almost certainly being over-written, in which case all bets are off. You could be corrupting any other piece of data.

If `len` is placed in memory immediately following `nod`, this memory overflow would explain why it's being changed. The following diagram will (attempt to) illustrate this. Let's say your `nod` definition is:

```
int nod[3][2];
```

but you attempt to set `nod[1-3][1-2]` instead of `nod[0-2][0-1]`:

```
      +-----------+
+0000 | nod[0][0] |
      +-----------+
+0004 | nod[0][1] |
      +-----------+
+0008 | nod[1][0] |
      +-----------+
+000c | nod[1][1] |
      +-----------+
+0010 | nod[2][0] |
      +-----------+
+0014 | nod[2][1] |
      +-----------+
+0018 |   len[0]  | and nod[3][0], should you be foolish enough to try :-)
      +-----------+
+001c |   len[1]  | and nod[3][1] *
      +-----------+
+0020 |   len[2]  | and nod[3][2] *
      +-----------+
```

C/C++ will not check regular array bounds for overflow. So, if you attempt to set `nod[3][something-or-other]`, you'll find yourself in trouble very similar to what your question describes.

The bit patterns you're using (3 and 4) equate to IEEE754 single-precision 4.2x10<sup>-45</sup> and 5.6x10<sup>-45</sup> respectively so they'd certainly give `0.0000` when printing (since you don't appear to be using a format string which would give you the more precise value).

A good way to test this theory would be to output the `len` variables immediately before and after setting the relevant `nod` variables, something like:

```
printf ("before: len1 = %f, len2 = %f\n", len[1], len[2]);
nod[3][1] = 3;
nod[3][2] = 4;
printf ("after : len1 = %f, len2 = %f\n", len[1], len[2]);
```

Actual details as to how the variables are laid out in memory may be different to that described above but the theory still holds.

Two possible solutions if that turns out to be the problem.

- Use zero-base arrays as C/C++ intended; or
- Define them with enough space to handle your unusual use, such as `int nod[4][3]`.

Comment: Agreed. I added 1 for every declaration *(as in float len[ELEM+1];)* to account for start value as 1. But the culprit turned out to be in #define of NODE (nod is float nod[NODE+1][3]) itself. It was one less than intended. :( Thanks for your detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have a buffer overwrite. Check your boundaries, you don't provide any array size in your example, making us unable to say more than that.

If you'using C++, try to replace your arrays by std::tr1::array or boost::array (they are the same), that will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a [*watchpoint*](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_6.html#SEC35) in gdb to see when `len` is being modified.  Make sure to compile your program with debug information (`-g`) and no optimization (`-O0`).  Then, set a breakpoint near the declaration of `len`, add a watchpoint with `watch len[0]`, and run.  gdb will break whenever `len[0]` is modified, and it will tell you the new and the old value.